# What is a pill's "envelope" called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What is the name of the "envelope" that pills come in?

Example: "I recently bought some ___________ of pills that will help me with my headaches".

A photo of the "envelope" is included for reference:

[image: A photo of the "envelope" is included for reference]

Comment: They're called bubble packs.

Comment: To me, in American English, it sounds stilted to refer to the container at all in your sentence. I would say "I bought some pills...". If you want to emphasize there are multiple types of pill, maybe "I bought some different pills...". And really, you didn't buy them in blister packs, you bought them in boxes.

Comment: Would have posted as a comment, but can't.
I have also heard people call them "maps", as in: "-I got a map of caffeine pills and took them all at once, now I can smell sounds and hear scents, please send help"

Comment: In India they're referred to as strips, and usually contain 10, 15 or 20 pills.  That means both the blister packs and all-foil ones.  I would ask my wife "get me two strips of paracetamol".

Comment: Interesting term for that, I've never heard it. Is it particular to a certain region?

Comment: This is a term from the recreational drug-user community, and probably would not be used in reference to prescription or otc drugs. Grip, dime, and lid are similar words.

Comment: But I DID bought them by blisters, not by boxes, that's how the question popped into my mind, Jeremy Nottingham.

Answer (score 52):

That's a [blister pack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_pack).

I haven't seen 'blister pack' used in a sentence as you demonstrate, though. I might say "I recently bought some packs of pills..." or just "I recently bought some pills..."

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've never used the word before and it feels kind of off. I actually gave a vague example because I actually needed the exact amount of pills for the description, originally I did use "I bought some packs of pills" just as you say, but then I felt I needed more depth, in the lines of "I bought some pills for the headeaches, three blister packs with ten pills each. That should do the trick for a month..."

Comment: @JuanDavidGamboa In Guatemalan Spanish we use the _anglicismo "blister"_. You don´t say that in Colombia?

Comment: @Cascabel Woah, wait, what? who told you that? *looks suspiciously to both sides*. Yes, apparently we do, just checked the dictionary, but as I mentioned, I had never heard that word before.

Comment: @Juan It doesn't seem like you really need to reference the packaging, just the quantity... I would probably say "I bought a month's supply".

Comment: If you feel the need to reference the packaging, refer to the *external* packaging, which is typically a box that contains one or more blister packs: "I bought a box of pills."

Comment: I have used this phrase before, generally in a sentence very like "*I can't get the pill out of this @#$% blister pack*".

Comment: Similarly, I've heard them called "packets" when there are multiples or "pack" or "blister pack" when there is only one.